# React native azure notification hub

Tags: azure, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, azure-notificationhub

I am using [this](https://github.com/CatalystCode/react-native-azurenotificationhub) library to implement azure notification hub in react native.
I am able to get the registration ID successfully. But no notification is received.
I am sending test notification from azure portal and it is getting delivered successfully.
I am followed the integration tutorial from [here](https://github.com/CatalystCode/react-native-azurenotificationhub#android-installation) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-android-push-notification-google-fcm-get-started).

In my manifest file i am getting this error in red. Could [image: this] be the reason.
If yes, How do i resolve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the same [steps](https://github.com/CatalystCode/react-native-azurenotificationhub#android-installation) and had the same issue with `com.microsoft.windowsazure.notifications.NotificationsBroadcastReceiver` being unreferenced. I was able to resolve by adding

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.microsoft.azure:notification-hubs-android-sdk:0.6@aar'
    implementation 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-notifications-handler:1.0.1@aar'
 }

 repositories {
     maven {
         url "https://dl.bintray.com/microsoftazuremobile/SDK"
     }
 }
```

to my app build.gradle as outlined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-android-push-notification-google-fcm-get-started#adding-azure-notification-hubs-libraries)

[image: AndroidManifest.xml]

It may or may not make a difference but also make sure you have the x86 Atom image installed to the project

[image: Project SDKs]

Comment: Hi ryan thank you for your comment. Are you able to receive the notifications on your android device ?

Comment: hi ryan, the reference issue got resolved, but still not able to receive notifications on my mobile device. Do let me know if you were able to receive the notifications or not ?

Comment: Hey @sumesh, the test app I created is based off `react-native init myapp` but from there, I didn't know where or how to integrate [this](https://github.com/CatalystCode/react-native-azurenotificationhub#android-1) code block in the react app. So I followed this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-android-push-notification-google-fcm-get-started#updating-the-androidmanifestxml) filling in the empty gaps and was successful in getting notifications to the emulator.